# A question about closed (but not necessarily compact) connected subsets of Euclidean spaces.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Is the following statement true?......

> If $C$ is a non-degenerate closed and connected subset of the
>   Euclidean plane $\mathbb R ^2$ and $p$ is any point of $C$, then there
>   exists a connected subset of $C$ which contains p and has an
>   arbitrarily small positive diameter.

If the answer is "yes", is this statement still true for any finite dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: What about a line?

Comment: What does non-degenerate mean ?

Comment: The topologist's sine curve in the plane is a counterexample. It's also compact.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma On $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$, you can take $\{0\}\times ([y_0-\varepsilon,y_0+\varepsilon]\cap [-1,1])$ as a connected subset with diameter $\leqslant 2\varepsilon$ containing $(0,y_0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer my bad, I sort of assumed it had to be a neighbourhood. Oh well.

Comment: @Garabed Since I got no response to my answer I think maybe something is misunderstood: Note that I do not need $C$ to be compact.  I apply the boundary bumping theorem in $\gamma C$ and then note that the component is actually contained in $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes it also holds in any finite dimensional Euclidean space.

Let $C$ be a closed connected subset of $\mathbb R ^n$.

Then $C$ has a compactification $\gamma C$ (such as $\text{cl}_{[-\infty,\infty]^n} C$), and will be open in $\gamma C$ because it is locally compact.

Let $c\in C$ and let $U=B(c,\epsilon)$ be an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $c$.  Note that $U$ is also open in $\gamma C$. By the boundary bumping theorem for connected compact Hausdorff spaces, the component $K$ of $c$ in $U$ meets the boundary (in $\gamma X$) of $U$.  Then $K$ is nontrivial, $c\in K\subseteq C$ and $K$ diameter less than $2\epsilon$.

Note: You do not really need $C$ to be closed; it could be open also.  The important thing is that it is locally compact. You could have a big problem if $C$ is not locally compact.  Consider the Knaster-Kuratowski fan in $\mathbb R ^2$. No point other than the dispersion point has connected sets around it of small diameter.

Comment: @ Forever Mozart: Many thanks for your response and that very nice proof.

Comment: @ Captain Lama: The term "non-degenerate" means "containing at least two points".

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian Thanks.  By the way, you seem to ask a lot of questions (here and on MathOverflow) that are interesting to me, mostly the ones dealing with strange connectedness properties.  And you ask about many open problems too, perhaps without knowing it.  By the way, did you ever solve this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36017/a-question-about-the-dispersion-points-of-connected-metric-spaces ?  I've been thinking about it for a while but no proof.

Comment: @ Forever Mozart: No., I could not get anywhere with that problem.  But there is another statement connected with the present problem which  I feel is almost surely true and should be very easy to prove . Yet I cannot prove it. "If C is unbounded , then any two distinct  points of C are contained in some compact sub-continuum of C." I have spent a lot of time trying to construct counter-examples-with no success.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian I think that is false.  Take the buckethandle continuum, delete a point from it, and then stretch the "hole" to infinity.  I am pretty sure that points in different stretched composants cannot be joined by a compact subcontinuum.  I could give some details if you want to post a question about this.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian I found a much simpler counterexample.  Take$C$ to be the graph of $(\sin (1/x))/x$, together with the $y$-axis.  This set will be connected and closed in the plane.  Pick a point on the $y$-axis, and another point on the curve.  These cannot be joined by a continuum in $C$.  Do you see why?

Comment: You are right. The statement is false. I finally stumbled on Counter-example No: 122-entitled "Nested Angles"- in the book "Counter-examples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach. No compact sub-continuum of this Counter-example can contain both a point on the x-axis and a point not on the x-axis. You can see this clearly when you look at the diagram. Your sine Counter-example is really neat, I don't know how I got off on such a wrong track. Of course,  the statement is true if C is locally connected because then C is arc-wise connected.